# Create a daemon with upstart that logs stderr to certain users console?

Tags: linux, unix, upstart

I have an upstart script that I wrote which calls a script and starts watching files, etc (actually its a wrapper around gulp that will compile SCSS to CSS).

The problem is if someone saves an error to the SCSS file the watcher will crash. I know how to respawn the daemon no problem:

```
respawn
respawn limit 5 10
```

But I *also* want to alert the user that the watcher crashed so they can fix the syntax error (or whatever it happens to be).

If I know the username I want to target, is it possible to somehow either switch to the username before daemonizing or hook into that users console so that I can write messages to them if the daemon crashes?

Comment: There is no guarantee that your user is logged in, or logged in exactly once. The traditional solution is to send email.

Comment: Its for a development machine. If the watch gets triggered because a file changed, it means that the developer is logged in making changes (and they all use the same development login). My new idea is to echo the output to all pty/[1-9] in use. Haven't tried it yet though.

Comment: The `wall` command can be used to message all logged-in users who have a terminal open.